# HTML5 / PHP form suddenly won't send mail

Tags: php, html, forms, email

Basically this was working correctly a couple days ago and I tested it again on MAMP today and I'm no longer receiving the emails so mail() isn't firing? Please help.

This is my form in my index page

```
<form method="POST" action="form.php">

<label>Name</label>
<input name="name" placeholder="Full Name" required>
<label>Email</label>
<input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email Address" required>    
<label>Company</label>
<input name="company" type="text" placeholder="Your Company" required>    
<input  type="hidden" name="robots" value="" required/>
<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

and this is my external form.php file

```
<?php
$name = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['name']));
$email = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
$company = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['company']));
$robots = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['robots']));
$from = 'From:RegisterForm'; 
$to = 'sofi.smith@blah.com';
$subject = 'Lead';

$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n company: $company\n ";

if($_POST['submit']) {
 if($robots == '') {
    if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
    header('Location: thank-you-page.html');
    } else {
        echo '<p>Something went wrong, please try again</p>'; 
    }
} else  {
    echo 'Sorry, we don\'t like spammers here!';
}
}

?><!doctype html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Mamp php log shows no errors in the log apart from the depreciated element and when I remove this it makes no difference? [image: MAMP php error log]

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string requires a valid mysql connection, but does not need to be passed explicitly. In mysqli_real_escape_string() that needs to be passed explicitly. Try removing mysql_real_escape_string(), since on failure it might return no string and u may get empty values.

Comment: I tried this so that it was simply
    $name = (strip_tags($_POST['name']));

But still no better :(

Comment: hmm looks like something wrong in the out going server or u may check the header part since it does not look good. Check the answer from @Adrian

Comment: So there's nothing noticeably wrong with my code? I have removed the header and tried to echo 'success' which works, but still no email?

Comment: Okay, the very first thing you might want to do is to figure out if `mail()` returns `true` (which means successful delivering). Try to `var_dump(mail(.....))` in isolation, what it says?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use **correct** mail headers From: XXX\n is **incorrect** Use From: XXX\r\n. A Name-Value Pair of a valid header is **Name: Value\r\n**
2. use an PHPMailer-Class
3. Mails wont send? Your server is not configurated for sending mails. Contact the server admin!

Comment: I was going to go with the from email is not a valid email. Most servers block that..

Comment: From: Name <E-Mail>\r\n for example From: Max Lastname <info@mymail.com>\r\n